# Can I send both HTML and PHP files in express.js?

Tags: javascript, php, html, express

Say I have an express.js app running a webpage. Can I send HTML files for one page, and PHP files for another?

Theoretical Example:

```
var express = require('express.js')
var app = express()

app.get('/php', function (req, res) {
res.sendFile('__dirname + '/index.php')
})

app.get('/html', function (req, res) {
res.sendFile('__dirname + '/index.html')
})

app.listen(3000)
```

Comment: First, show us some effort. What have you tried so far. Second... you can send any file using expressJS. Question is, what do you want to achieve. To vie php file properly, you need php interpreter. But technically , yes. You can send php as a plaintext file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using php-express to serve php files on express https://www.npmjs.com/package/php-express